# Alarmmanager schedule the same pending intent to fire twice at the same time

Tags: android

My intent was supposed to be fired once every 30 seconds. since I'm using Android 5.0 for testing, the alarm api schedules and fires it with other alarm events every 20-40s.

```
        pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, 30000, pendingIntent);
```

sometimes the 2 of the same pending intent is scheduled to fire at the same time. This happens once in about 5 minutes. How can I avoid this?

Comment: please read AlarmManager docs, everything you need is there

Comment: After I strictly followed the docs it stopped happening. thanks